# SQL query takes lot of time to respond

Tags: mysql, sql-server, query-builder

I have a SQL query like

```
SELECT c.Case_Id, c.Disease_Sub_Type_Id, p.MedRecNo 
FROM case1 c, patient p, episode e, personal_medical_history pmh, reproductive_history rh 
WHERE c.Age <> '12' AND c.horizontal_spread <> '21' AND c.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
      AND e.Case_Id = c.Case_Id AND pmh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
      AND rh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
GROUP BY c.Case_Id`
```

when I use above query this gives me result quickly but when I use OR as condition like

```
SELECT c.Case_Id, c.Disease_Sub_Type_Id, p.MedRecNo 
FROM case1 c, patient p, episode e, personal_medical_history pmh, reproductive_history rh 
WHERE c.Age <> '12' OR c.horizontal_spread <> '21' AND c.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id AND e.Case_Id = c.Case_Id AND pmh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
      AND rh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id 
GROUP BY c.Case_Id`
```

I'm not getting output and MySQL getting hang. Is there any simple way to apply join or my approach is wrong?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Try wrapping your OR in parenthesis like this;

```
SELECT c.Case_Id
    ,c.Disease_Sub_Type_Id
    ,p.MedRecNo
FROM case1 c
    ,patient p
    ,episode e
    ,personal_medical_history pmh
    ,reproductive_history rh
WHERE (c.Age <> '12'
    OR c.horizontal_spread <> '21')
    AND c.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
    AND e.Case_Id = c.Case_Id
    AND pmh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
    AND rh.Patient_Id = p.Patient_Id
GROUP BY c.Case_Id`
```

Comment: Sure, it's best practice to wrap the OR statements in brackets otherwise it processes everything before and after as separate statements. If this has resolved the problem then feel free to mark as accepted answer and upvote.